# Set Iframe's height equal to its content

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, iframe, same-origin-policy

I've been struggling with this for a whole day, unbelievable. I have an option at my site where users can download a full chat history with a certain user, instead of loading it online and most probably crashing their browser. Anyhow, when they request to download their history a zip archive is being created which contains files with history for each day - in case they do not have a strong enough machine to open them all at once and an index file which contains all history files in the form of Iframes ( instead of having the same content written on 2 places ).

**The problem**: All I want to do is set the Iframe's height equal to its content's height, amazingly this seems unfairly impossible in chrome due to its same-origin policy. I first thought I could just get the child Iframe's body scrollHeight and be alright but then SOP said NO and smacked me across the face. Then I figured I could set the html tag's style.height to its complete height internally from the history file and then retrieve it but that failed as well.

I am really starting to lose hope, can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the page of the iframe content and the page where you call the iframe, put this:

```
<script>
    document.domain = 'http://yoursite.com'; (NOT www.)
</script>
```

Also make sure you call the iframe WITHOUT `www.`,

Do: `<iframe onload = "setIframeHeight( this.id )" ...>`

and `iFrameHeight()` goes like:

```
<script>
   document.domain = 'http://yoursite.com';
    function setIframeHeight( iframeId )
    {
     var ifDoc, ifRef = document.getElementById( iframeId );
     try
     {   
      ifDoc = ifRef.contentWindow.document.documentElement;  
     }
     catch( e )
     { 
      try
      { 
       ifDoc = ifRef.contentDocument.documentElement;  
      }
      catch(ee)
      {   
      }  
     }
     if( ifDoc )
     {
      ifRef.height = 1;  
      ifRef.height = ifDoc.scrollHeight;  
     }
 </script>
```

I'm not sure at all if this will work for you, but for me it did.

Answer (score 0):

This Video on Marakana TechTV contains good tips for seemless iframe integration:

[iFrame usage with postMessage and seamless emulation at DisQus](http://marakana.com/s/post/1301/seamless_iframes_future_disqus_video)

Furthermore there is a jQuery plugin ( havent tested ) which claims to provide the functionality.

[house9/jquery-iframe-auto-height](https://github.com/house9/jquery-iframe-auto-height)

Comment: Thank you for the amazingly quick answers. Those are great examples but unfortunately I don't have a server to use postMessage on the client's local machine as well as I cannot just make users download a whole plugin just to resize their iframes. The problem with chrome is that it treats any file that is opened via file:// ( not http:// ) as a separate origin and setting document.origin doesn't seem to make any big of a difference.

Summary - Sadly, I need to be able to access a child Iframe using file:// protocol.

@Laurent